# animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-animate, setinterval

i want to make a simple jquery slider, i dont know jquery very well, so i decided to ask u guys, here is some inf about slider:

javascript:

```
setInterval(function() {
        $('#scroll').animate({top: -200}, 500);
        },1000);
```

html:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="scroll">
        <div class="content">1</div>
        <div class="content">2</div>
        <div class="content">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#slider { height:200px; width:200px; background:#dfdfdf; overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
#scroll { position:absolute; }
.content { height:200px; width:200px; color:#000; }
```

the only thing it does, just animate from 1st to 2nd div, but i need to animate it endlessly, and not only from 1 to a 2 but also to 3rd one. then from 3 to a 1st and etc.. pls smb help!

Comment: Why not use JqueryUI? http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider

Comment: i dont know how to use it ^.^

Comment: lol... I would use jqueryUI..

Comment: But *that* slider is not what venom is asking for.

Comment: I would go for something more like jQuery cycle Plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these (carousels)

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/jquery-carousel-plugins-tutorials/

http://bxslider.com/